# How can I unzip a mysql longblob field made in python?

Tags: python, mysql

I have a field in a mysql of type longblob,
The data was saved from python

```
    @classmethod
    def dataToObject(cls, data):
        if data:
            try:
                data = zlib.decompress(data)
            except zlib.error:
                pass
            if isinstance(data, unicode):
                data = data.encode("utf8")
            try:
                return cPickle.loads(data)
            except:
                return ErrorResponse("Can't Recovery Data")

    @classmethod
    def objectToData(cls, record):
        return zlib.compress(cPickle.dumps(record))

    @property
    def Object(self):
        return self.dataToObject(self.Data)

    @Object.setter
    def Object(self, record):
        self.Data = self.objectToData(record)
```

I tried to unzip it in mysql with convert char

I tried PHP with zlib_decode but it returns

```
b "" "
ccore.Record \ n
PythonRecordToRecord \ n
p1 \ n
((ibase.tools.PythonRecord \ n
PythonRecord \ n
(dp2 \ n
S '__ newflag __' \ n
p3 \ n
I01 \ n
sS'fields' \ n
p4 \ n
(dp5 \ n
S'TransTime '\ n
p6 \ n
cdatetime \ n
time \ n
p7 \ n
(S '\ x0f \ x13 \ x12 \ x00 \ x00 \ x00' \ n
tRp8 \ n
sS'TotalBase2d '\ n
p9 \ n
F782.56999999999994 \ n
sS'DiffBase1 '\ n
p10 \ n
F0 \ n
sS'SerNr '\ n
p11 \ n
L100236529L \ n
sS'DiffBase2 '\ n
```

I'm just starting with python but this data compression is out of my leage.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: you use `cPickle` in Python but PHP doesn't have command to unpickle it - so don't use pickle. Better use JSON to convert data to string - probably all languages have function or module for JSON.

Comment: The python code is generated by our ERP, but we have a legal dispute. So if I use the unpickle command from python could I access the data? If it is simple log data.

Comment: if  some class was pickled then you would need import this class to unpickle it (even in Python). I see `PythonRecordToRecord`, `ibase.tools.PythonRecord`. etc in code and it can be class which you would have to import.